# How to compare two particular ordinals?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Assume that $n \ge 1$.

Let $\alpha_n$ denote the least countable ordinal that is not $\Delta_n^L$-definable.

Let $x_n$ denote a real which encodes all countable ordinals that are $\Delta_n^L$-definable.

Let $y_n$ denote a real which encodes all subsets of $\omega$ that are $\Delta_n^L$-definable.

Let $\beta_n^z$ denote the least countable ordinal that is not $\Delta_n$-definable in $L[z]$ with a predicate for $z$.

Question $1$: Which ordinal is larger, $\alpha_{n+1}$ or $\beta_n^{x_n}$? If they are equal, why?

Question $2$: Which ordinal is larger, $\alpha_{n+1}$ or $\beta_n^{y_n}$? If they are equal, why?

I am interested in all cases ($V = L$; $V \neq L$; no sharps exist; sharps exist for all subsets of $\omega$; sharps exist, but not for all subsets of $\omega$).

Comment: We also need to care how to define $x_n$: for example, assume that $0^\sharp$ exists, and $x_n$ codes not only all $\Delta_n^L$-definable countable ordinals but also $0^\sharp$. (This is possible when, for example, $x_n\subseteq\omega\times\omega$ codes every countable $\Delta_n^L$-definable well-order and $\{m\mid (m,n)\in x\}$ codes the ordertype $\omega$ iff $n\in 0^\sharp$.) In that case, $\Sigma_m^L\subseteq \Delta_1^{L[x_n]}$ holds for any $m$ since we can decode the truth predicate of $L$ from $0^\sharp$. Especially, we have $\alpha_m\le \beta_1^{x_n}$ for all $m<\omega$.

Comment: @HanulJeon: I have edited the question, so now $y_n$ takes sharps into account. I am not sure I fully understand the previous comment: what is the condition for the value of $n$ in $\alpha_m \le \beta_1^{x_n}$?

Comment: $n$ is also arbitrary. You may simply take $n=1$.

Comment: @HanulJeon: it seems that here we need to know the complexity of the definition of zero sharp. I know that $0^{\sharp}$ is $\Delta_3^1$-definable, but what is the minimal value of $n$ such that $0^{\sharp}$ is definable by some formula of complexity $\Delta_n$ in the [Lévy hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lévy_hierarchy)?

Comment: The set of all reals is $\Pi_1$-definable, so I think $0^\sharp$ is $\Delta_2$-definable: let $\phi(x)$ be a $\Delta^1_3$-formula defining $0^\sharp$. Replace every occurring of $\mathbb{R}$ to a variable, say, $y$ to get a formula $\psi(x,y)$. $\psi$ would be $\Delta_0$, and then both of $\forall y (y=\mathbb{R})\to \psi(x,y)$ and $\exists y (y=\mathbb{R})\land \psi(x,y)$ define $0^\sharp$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @HanulJeon points out, it is very important how exactly $x_n$ is defined. But let's suppose we define it in the following reasonably minimal manner: $x_n$ is the $L$-least wellorder of $\omega$ in ordertype $\alpha_n$, and $y_n$ is the $L$-least real which is Turing above all subsets of $\omega$ which are $\Delta_n^L$-definable.

I'm also going to assume $n>0$, as I'm not exactly sure how to interpret $\Delta_0^L$-definability.

Then $\alpha_{n+1}>\beta_n^{x_n}=\beta_n^{y_n}$.

The main point here is that $\alpha_n<\alpha_{n+1}$.
For this, first suppose $n=1$. Let $\lambda_1$ be the least ordinal such that $L_{\lambda_1}\preccurlyeq_1 L$. Then $\{\lambda_1\}$ is $\Sigma_2^L$-definable. But using the parameter $\lambda_1$ it is easy to compute $\alpha_1$ itself, so $\alpha_1<\alpha_2$. When $n>1$ it is similar. (Actually $\lambda_1=\alpha_1<\omega_1^L$, but that is special to the case $n=1$; easily $\omega_1^L<\lambda_2$.)

Similarly, for each real $x$, we have $\beta_n^x<\beta_{n+1}^x$.

Now because $\alpha_n<\alpha_{n+1}$, we get that $x_n$ and $y_n$ are both $\Delta_{n+1}^L$-definable (this also uses that from any ordinal $\beta<\omega_1^L$,
we can $\Sigma_1^L$-in-parameter-$\beta$ compute the least $\gamma\geq\beta$
such that $L_\gamma$ is pointwise definable, and applying this to $\beta=\alpha_n$,
we can determine $x_n$ and $y_n$ from the theory of this $L_\gamma$).

It follows that $\beta_n^{x_n}<\beta_{n+1}^{x_n}=\alpha_{n+1}$ and $\beta_n^{y_n}<\beta_{n+1}^{y_n}=\alpha_{n+1}$.

Comment: I have some questions about your answer: first, you defined $lambda_1$ as the least ordinal such that $L_{\lambda_1}\prec L$. Is it a typo of $L_{\lambda_1}\prec_{\Sigma_1} L$? Also, I do not see how to compute $\alpha_1$ from $\lambda_1$. Could you elaborate on how to do this?

Comment: Is this answer based on the assumption that $0^{\sharp}$ does not exist?

Comment: @HanuelJeon Yes, thanks, it was supposed to be $L_{\lambda_1}\preccurlyeq_1 L$, and I have corrected it now. Given $\lambda_1$ as a parameter, and (say) $\Sigma_1$-definability (over $L$), we can recover $L_{\lambda_1}$, and hence compute definability over $L_{\lambda_1}$, in particular $\Sigma_1$-over-$L_{\lambda_1}$, and use this to compute the set of ordinals which are $\Sigma_1$-over-$L_{\lambda_1}$-definable, and hence their supremum, which is $\alpha_1$ (because $L_{\lambda_1}\preccurlyeq_1 L$, and in particular, $\alpha_1\leq\lambda_1$).

Comment: The same works for $\lambda_n,\alpha_n$. But actually, $\lambda_1=\alpha_1$, because if $L\models\varphi$ where $\varphi$ is $\Sigma_1$, then by taking a countable hull we get some $\gamma<\omega_1^L$ such that $L_\gamma\models\varphi$. But the for all $\xi\geq\gamma$, we have $L_\xi\models\varphi$ (note this is special for $\Sigma_1$). But $\lambda_1$ is then just the sup of all such $\gamma$, which is therefore ${<\omega_1^L}$, and note that if $\gamma<\lambda_1$ then $\{\gamma\}$ is $\Sigma_1^L$-definable (cofinally many $\xi<\omega_1^L$ are such that $L_\xi$ is pointwise definable).

Comment: @lyricallywicked No, it doesn't matter about $0^\#$, as $x_n,y_n$ have been chosen definably in $L$.